# My inputs doesn't work wil fullpage scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, fullpage.js

I am using Full page js, and for some reasons my input's doesn't work, I can't even press. Please help

```
<div class="contact">
                        <form action="#">
                            <label for="fname"></label><br>
                            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Name">
                            <label for="email"></label>
                            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                            <label for="company-name"></label>
                            <input type="text" id="company-name" name="company-name" placeholder="Company name">
                            <input type="submit" value="Enroll">
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

JS:

```
if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1800) {
        $("#fullpage").fullpage({});
    }
}
```

Comment: Invisible div above the inputs? What if you right-click an input then inspect? Is it really the input element or some invisible element covering it?

Comment: Try applying CSS z-index

Comment: What fullpage initialisation are you using? Are you using scrollOverflow? Try turning that off.